# WMIC commands to change computer name to BIOS serial number

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm new with batch file and wmic and after researching StackOverflow I've found few answers which overlap but not producing expected output when put together.

Problem:

Create a batch file to change computer name (not on domain):

1. use `wmic bios get serialnumber` and assign the value to the variable `comp_name`, then display the value of this variable;
2. change computer name to the value of the variable `comp_name`;

So for 1.:

```
FOR /F %%F IN ('wmic bios get serialnumber') DO (
SET comp_name=%%F
)
ECHO %comp_name%
```

Followed by 2.:

```
WMIC computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%%comp_name%%
```

edit: got a 1. part correct - works as expected - fetching serial number and displays the variable's value. However part 2. still throwing errors:

```
O:\>wmic computersystem where name="TOM-PC" rename NAME=
Invalid named parameter list.
Hint: <named param list> ::= <named param> | <named param> <named param list> where <named param> ::= <param name>=<param value>
```

If I understand correctly - the `NAME=...` part of the last command don't recognise variable initialised above. So how to use a `comp_name` as a parameter for `wmic` command?

edit .2

"Why are you using doubled % signs in name=%%comp_name%%?" by `aschipfl` - I reverted to my original question - used double `%` and now getting different error - 87 which tells me more about the problem. using singles `%` produce the error listed above. I'm not sure if the problems lies in single or doubles`%` or somewhere else.

edit .3

Further research shows that `wmic bios get serialnumber` returns in fact three values each in new line

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic bios get serialnumber
SerialNumber
BY3VF02
```

that is - `SerialNumber` string followed by actual serial number in new line and last one with just empty line. So (I hope) the final questions - how to assign only the second value to my variable please?

Comment: The `@` symbol in `ECHO %@comp_name%` is a typo, right? Why are you using doubled `%` signs in `name=%%comp_name%%`? In your `FOR /F` loop you need to enclose your `wmic` command line in `''` like `('wmic bios get serialnumber')`, and remove the `USEBACKQ` option!

Comment: OK FIRST EDIT forgot @ during variable declaration

Comment: The `@` stuff is still not consistent throughout your question; I would simply remove it after all... Another thing: I think `wmic` does not feature a `rename` verb, perhaps you mean `set` instead; anyway, the `Name` property is read-only, so you won't succeed like this...

Comment: A apologise for the syntax of the question - I will do more research and update the question/problem.

Comment: I don't understand down votes - I have followed instructions from https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2009/02/19/renaming-a-computer-using-wmic-and-how-to-get-around-that-aggravating-invalid-global-switch-error/ , put everything together and still getting errors..

Comment: Note that down-votes have nothing to do with errors in your code, they are purely linked to the post as such; I did a down-vote because of the inconsistencies in your question post, which I mentioned before; you have corrected them meanwhile, so I retracted that vote now. Concerning the `wmic` command line: you have forgotten the `CALL` verb: `WMIC computersystem where name="%computername%" CALL rename name="%comp_name%"` (note also the quotes around `%comp_name%` which are necessary I guess)...

Answer (score 2):

Give a try for this batch code :

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "tokens=2 Delims==" %%A In ('WMIC Bios Get SerialNumber /Value') Do (
    For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do (
        Call :RenamePC "%%B" 
        Call :Ask4Reboot
    )
)
pause & Exit /B
::**********************************************************************
:RenamePC
WMIC ComputerSystem where Name="%ComputerName%" call Rename Name="%~1"
Exit /B
::***********************************************************************
:Ask4Reboot
(
    echo    Set Ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell"^)
    echo    Answ = MsgBox("Did you want to reboot your computer ?"_
    echo ,VbYesNo+VbQuestion,"Did you want to reboot your computer ?"^)
    echo    If Answ = VbYes then 
    echo        Return = Ws.Run("cmd /c shutdown -r -t 60 -c ""You need to reboot in 1 minute."" -f",0,True^)
    echo    Else
    echo        wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    End If
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Start "" "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following, *as long as your bios serials are valid computer names*, should do it:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC Bios Get SerialNumber'
    ) Do For /F "Delims=" %%B In ("%%A") Do Call :RenPC %%B
Exit/B
:RenPC
WMIC ComputerSystem Where Name!="%~1" Call Rename Name="%~1"
```

*The PC will have to be rebooted before the new name will take effect.*

Comment: Which bit doesn't work, the first loop doesn't retrieve the serial number, the second loop doesn't extract the variable, the second loop doesn't perform the rename, the rename doesn't persist upon a reboot. _(I have had issues with `!=` before, perhaps trying `<>` instead may fix it)_.

Comment: It's the "Where Name!="%*"." A better way to select the local system is shown below, based on my limited testing: "where Name="%ComputerName%""

Comment: I found why this fails . . . if using this one in a batch script where `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` is being utilized, it's going to error out because the `!` is not escaped.  If you use `delayedexpansion` - you must escape the `!` with `^^!` for it to work.

Comment: You should only have delayed variable expansion enabled where required @k1dfr0std, not for an entire script without good cause. It isn't enabled in my above example because it isn't needed. Even if it was necessary, I already offered a solution for that in my initial comment, i.e. replace `!=` with `<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Found this batch here:
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1912255-batch-file-to-use-wmic-commands-to-change-computer-name

Worked for Win 10 Ent v1803.
If you need prefix etc, simply add to name before / after variable.

```
setlocal
wmic bios get serialnumber | find /I /V "SerialNumber" > "%temp%\sn.txt"
set /p comp_name=<"%temp%\sn.txt"
wmic computersystem where name="%computername%" rename name=%comp_name%
del "%temp%\sn.txt"
endlocal
```